# Printing value of a variable through loops

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am using the for loop to print the below variables using the below statement but its not printing the values correctly. Its giving only the iteration value. Can someone help me?

```
value1="1500067"
value2="1500068"
value3="1500069"
package1="CNN"
package2="FOX"
package3="Discovery"

for iteration in {1..3}
do
echo ""$value""$iteration" - "$package""$iteration""
done
```

**Expected Output:**

```
1500067 - CNN
1500068 - Fox
1500069 - Discovery
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should really use arrays for this kind of task:

```
#!/bin/bash
values=( 
    1500067
    1500068
    1500069
)
packages=( 
    CNN 
    FOX 
    Discovery
)

for (( i=0; i < ${#values[@]}; i++ )); do
    echo "${values[i]} - ${packages[i]}"
done
```

Or, since you have natural key-value pairs, an associative array

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A packages=( 
    [1500067]=CNN 
    [1500068]=FOX 
    [1500069]=Discovery
)

for key in "${!packages[@]}"; do
    echo "$key - ${packages[$key]}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to accomplish this using the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
value1="1500067"
value2="1500068"
value3="1500069"
package1="CNN"
package2="FOX"
package3="Discovery"

for i in {1..3}; do
    var1="value$i"
    var2="package$i"
    echo "${!var1} - ${!var2}"
done
```

Your double quoting of the echo command is overkill, you have actually unquoted the variables because of the way it was setup.  Simply wrapping the entire argument in a single pair of quotes is fine.  If you run into a situation where you need to butt something up against your variable it's better to use brackets to preserve it's name:

`${var1}_something_else`

Be aware though that despite the `#!/bin/sh` hashbang, I believe this contains some bash-isms `{1..3}` and the indirect references `${1var}`.  It works on my system though.